# Setting up JS debugging with IntelliJ/WebStorm and PhantomJS/Casper

Tags: intellij-idea, phantomjs, casperjs, webstorm, javascript-debugger

Can I get an interactive JS debugger working on PhantomJS and/or CasperJS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PhantomJS has a `remote-debugger-port` option you can use to debug your casper script in Chrome dev tools. To use it, simply execute your casper script with this argument:

`casperjs test script.js --remote-debugger-port=9000`

Then, open up http://localhost:9000 in Chrome and click on the `about:blank` link that presents itself. You should then find yourself in familiar Chrome dev tools territory.

Since this is a script and not a web page, in order to start debugging, you have to do one of two things before your script will execute:

1. In the Chrome dev tools page, open the console and execute `__run()` to *actually start* your script.
2. Insert a `debugger;` line in your code, and run your casper script with an additional `--remote-debugger-autorun=yes` argument. Doing so with the remote debug page open will run the script until it hits your `debugger;` line.

There's a great [tutorial](https://drupalize.me/blog/201410/using-remote-debugger-casperjs-and-phantomjs) that explains this all very nicely.

Answer (score 15):

I didn't solve this entirely, but I definitely reduced the pain.

PhantomJS provides a [command line argument](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Troubleshooting) to enable [webkit's remote debugger](https://www.webkit.org/blog/1620/webkit-remote-debugging/).  AFAIK, PhantomJS launches a server and dumps the script into the `<head>` of a webpage with the familiar in-browser debugger.  It's actually pretty nice, with breakpoints, etc.  However, switching to manually digging around in the terminal for a random command line parameter and the path to your script is seriously irritating.

So, I used IntelliJ's "external tools" feature to launch a Bash script that kills any previous debugging session, launches PhantomJS, and then opens the page up in Chrome.

```
#!/bin/bash

lsof -i tcp@0.0.0.0:9000 #list anything bound to port 9000
if [ $? -eq 0 ] #if something was listed
    then
        killall 'phantomjs'
fi

/usr/local/Cellar/phantomjs/2.0.0/bin/phantomjs --remote-debugger-port=9000 $1 & 
# --remote-debugger-autorun=yes <- use if you have added 'debugger;' break points
# replace $1 with full path if you don't pass it as a variable.

sleep 2; #give phantomJS time to get started

open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app http://localhost:9000 & #linux has a different 'open' command
# alt URL if you want to skip the page listing
# http://localhost:9000/webkit/inspector/inspector.html?page=1

#see also
#github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

The next few lines are settings for IntelliJ, although the above code works just as well on any platform/IDE.

program: `$ProjectFileDir$/path/to/bash/script.sh`
parameters: `$FilePath$`
working dir: `$ProjectFileDir$`

Comment: In Chrome it is --remote-debugging-port, not --remote-debugger-port. That's also the flag in the webkit article. You might want to double-check that the flag is correct.

Comment: Nope, it's [definitely](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Troubleshooting#remote-debugging) `--remote-debugger-port=9000`

Comment: While this answer has gotten me plenty of internet points, I would like to see a *REAL* solution to this sometime and I would be happy to award the answer to anyone that can post it!

Comment: Here's a great [tutorial](https://drupalize.me/blog/201410/using-remote-debugger-casperjs-and-phantomjs) on using Remote debugging with casper/phantomjs.

Comment: @brettjonesdev Contribute a new answer!  I'd be happy to award an answer that gave real solution instead of this hack.  I'd do it myself but I've moved on from PhantomJS.